# Adobe AIR - Created image disk doesn't open

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to package an adobe air file for mac and the the resulting image file won't open. I'm working on a Mac and it's not the first time that i'm doing this. It seems so that my mac is the bad boy, because I tried also to package older projects and the resulting dmg files don't work too, but they used to worked.

Trying to open the image file I get following message:

```
"The following disk images couldn't be opened
PackagingTest.dmg - not recognized"
```

Has anyone any idea what it could be? I also repaired the mac permissions with disk utility, but it doesn't help.

Can anyone help me, please?

Solano

Comment: What version of AIR and what version of OS X? Could it possibly be an issue with Mavericks and you didn't update to 3.9 which I believe added support for Mavericks?

Comment: I'm using currently 10.8 and tested with the SDKs 3.5, 3.8, 3.9 and 4.0, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok people, finally found the problem. I'm using FDT and for some reason FDT stopped to append the flag `-target native` when compiling a native installer. I think that some FDT update introduced this bug.